# mongodb cant start centos 7

Tags: mongodb, centos7

I installed mongodb on Centos 7 and all works fine.

But if I reboot the system, mongodb can't start anymore. If I uninstall and install again, works fine. But after reboot, cant start anymore.

When I try systemctl status mongod.service shows:

> mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
>   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
>   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Dom 2016-11-27 09:49:36 BRT; 12min ago
>   Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
>   Process: 1471 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS run (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>   Main PID: 1471 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> Nov 27 09:49:19 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
>   Nov 27 09:49:19 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database...
>   Nov 27 09:49:36 localhost.localdomain mongod[1471]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
>   Nov 27 09:49:36 localhost.localdomain mongod[1471]: forked process: 2828
>   Nov 27 09:49:36 localhost.localdomain mongod[1471]: ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1
>   Nov 27 09:49:36 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mongod.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
>   Nov 27 09:49:36 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
>   Nov 27 09:49:36 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.

I already tried:

```
*chcon -R -t mongod_var_lib_t /var/lib/mongo
*SElinux=disable
*chmod 7777 /var/lib/mongo
and nothing.
```

I remember when this error appeared before I format my pc, I needed to put permission on systemd with a simple command. But I cant find anymore.

Comment: We need more information to debug this. Anything from the mongodb log file?

Answer (score 2):

here is the official bug report
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27241

in

```
 /usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service
```

update the systemd service with the following, till they fix it officially

```
    [Service]
    User=mongod
    Group=mongod
    Environment="OPTIONS=--quiet -f /etc/mongod.conf"
    PermissionsStartOnly=true
    ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir /var/run/mongodb
    ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown -R mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS run
    PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
```

Comment: add file location /usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service

Answer (score 0):

I remove and reinstall Mongodb 3.4
The server started with: sudo systemctl start mongod.service, and started ok.

Here's the **/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log**

> 2016-11-27T13:23:03.600-0300 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED
>
> ---
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:03.612-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB
>   starting : pid=8247 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongo 64-bit
>   host=localhost.localdomain
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:03.612-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version
>   v3.4.0-rc5
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:03.612-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version:
>   7df8fe1099135d137516f1670d2a0091ace63ca0
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:03.612-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL
>   version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:03.612-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator:
>   tcmalloc
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:03.612-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:03.612-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build
>   environment:
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:03.612-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod:
>   rhel70
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:03.612-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch:
>   x86_64
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:03.612-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>   target_arch: x86_64
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:03.612-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {
>   command: [ "run" ], config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp:
>   "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, processManagement: { fork: true,
>   pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid" }, storage: { dbPath:
>   "/var/lib/mongo", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: {
>   destination: "file", logAppend: true, path:
>   "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log", quiet: true } }
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:03.971-0300 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data
>   files  in /var/lib/mongo created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine,
>   so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:03.971-0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
>   wiredtiger_open config:
>   create,cache_size=1329M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:05.036-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:05.036-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING:
>   Access control is not enabled for the database.
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:05.036-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **
>   Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:05.036-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:05.036-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:05.036-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING:
>   /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:05.036-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We
>   suggest setting it to 'never'
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:05.036-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:05.036-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING:
>   /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:05.036-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We
>   suggest setting it to 'never'
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:05.036-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:05.061-0300 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing
>   full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/var/lib/mon`enter
>   code here`go/diagnostic.data'
>
> 2016-11-27T13:23:05.061-0300 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for
>   connections on port 27017

When i reboot the sytem, Mongodb wont start again.
Heres the log:

> logAppend: true   path: **/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log**
>
> *# Where and how to store data.
>
> 2016-11-27T13:30:27.927-0300 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED
>
> ---
>
> 2016-11-27T13:30:28.279-0300 I CONTROL  [main] ERROR: Cannot write pid
>   file to /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid: No such file or directory

Here is my **/etc/mongod.conf**

> storage:
>
> dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
>
> journal:
>       enabled: true
>
> *#  engine:
>
> *#  mmapv1:
>
> *#  wiredTiger:
>
> *# how the process runs
>
> processManagement:    fork: true  # fork and run in background
>   pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
>
> *# network interfaces net:   port: 27017   bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.
>
> *# security:
>
> *# operationProfiling:
>
> *# replication:
>
> *# sharding:
>
> *## Enterprise-Only Options
>
> *# auditLog:
>
> *# snmp:

Comment: I discovered the problem but i dont know how to fix it. Every time that i reboot the system, the folder /var/run/mongodb dissapear. I have to do sudo mkdir /var/run/mongodb and sudo chmod 777 -R /var/run/mongodb and sudo /sbin/restorecon -R /var/run/mongodb every time that i reboot the system. How i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into that on CentOS 7 and mongodb 3.4. Here's how I solved it:

1. Edit `/etc/mongod.conf` file and change **fork** to **false** and **pidFilePath** to the same as **dbPath** (which for me is /var/lib/mongo):

/etc/mongod.conf:

`storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo`

`processManagement:
  fork: false  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/lib/mongo/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile`

`net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0`

2. Don't forget to set firewall rules and reload:

`firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=27017/tcp; firewall-cmd --reload`

3. Follow log file and restart:

`tail -f /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log  &`

`systemctl restart mongod; systemctl status mongod`

4. You should see in last line of log file:

`NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017`

It worked for me, I rebooted the system and I could connect to mongo straight away.